# Getting attributes from models and displaying it within templates - Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Could someone check over the following code and tell me why I cannot output any attributes from my model to templates? My views and template render correctly the model does fetch data and this should work...

**Template:**

```
Name should show here --> {{thisItem}}
```

I get no error and text shows but no `{{thisItem}}`. From reading the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#itemview-serializedata) this should work.

I don't think my model is being passed to the template or is there a [dot] needed i.e. {{model.name}}?

**My View:**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/myModel',
    'collections/myModelCollection',
    'hbs!templates/testExampleTemplate.html',
], function ($, _, Backbone, myModel, myModelCollection, testExampleTemplate) {
    var thisView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.model.fetch();
        },
        model: new myModel(),
        template: testExampleTemplate,
    });
    return thisView;

});
```

**console.log of model showing I do have data:**

```
    attributes: Object
          thisItem: "Example Item"
```

**Model:**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'jquery'
], function (_, Backbone, jquery) {

    var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/myModel'
    });

    return myModel;

});
```

Template, this is how my works:

HTML Base

Layout view gets loaded into this i.e.

```
function (Marionette, Handlebars, template, jquery, model) {
    var LayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: template,
        regions: {
            holder1: "#holder1"
        }
    });
    return LayoutView;
});

<div id="holder1">I will be replaced</div>
```

Then the view in question gets loaded into holder1.

Comment: can you share your template please

Comment: Would need to see the template.

Comment: Hi @Rayweb_on my template only has in it the example I posted above it gets loaded into an area on the main page.

Comment: may be your underscore template engine expect for <%= => this declaration? you changed this?

Comment: yes I'm using Handerbars, but I tried it with underscore and text.js too and had the same issue with <%=  =>

Comment: @Rayweb_on this is the hbs.js file https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate/blob/master/public/js/libs/hbs.js

Comment: have you tried compiling your template? i have a small jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/gXemX/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an asynchronous issue.  You need to listen to your model's `change` event before you render.

Try adding

```
modelEvents: {
    'change': 'render'
}
```

To your View.  This will make sure your model has loaded its data before the view renders so your data shows up in your model.

Btw, `modelEvents` is specific to Marionette and not native to Backbone.  You can do this:

```
var self = this;
this.model.fetch({'success': function() {
    self.render();
});
```

In your initialize function if you want to rely on Backbone alone.

This works because your model doesn't load its data from the server immediately. It takes a moment, and your code keeps executing. So you are rendering before the data has loaded. By waiting until it's loaded you are ensuring the template will render with the data. You can remove your other render call from wherever that is, because the view is now rendering itself. Side note, this will allow it to rerender whenever the data changes automatically.

Comment: Ok I tried added modelEvents and yep it now works. could you explain more why??? On top of that I have now noticed it consoles out the model again does that mean it making two calls?

Comment: It works because your model doesn't load it's data from the server immediately.  It takes a moment, and your code keeps executing.  So you are rendering before the data has loaded.  By waiting until it's loaded you are ensuring the template will render with the data.  You can remove your other render call from wherever that is, because the view is now rendering itself.  Side note, this will allow it to rerender whenever the data changes automatically.

Comment: Cool that makes a lot of sense. What I have noticed tho is my render function now gets called twice, is that normal and does it cause any issues?

Comment: It's not normal.  Are you calling render to this View from another class?  What was causing it to render before?  It will now render itself when the model loads so you don't need any other render calls to it.

Comment: In the view itself I have a onRender:function() which I console out the model. I noticed that it now logs twice on load. Maybe this is correct as it does render twice, right?